# Definition of dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As I study Carothers' book, Real Analysis, I am attempting to form my own examples of his definitions.  On page 59 he writes

> A set $A$ is said to be dense in $M$ (or as some authors say, everywhere dense) if $\overline{A} = M$. $A$ is dense in $M$ if and only if any of the the following hold [My question is about (a); I am omitting (b), (c), and (d)]:
>   (a) Every point in $M$ is the limit of a sequence from $A$.

Is the following a valid example of statement (a)?

Let $M = (0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and let $A = \{ 0,1 \}$.  Then $\overline{A} = M$.

Comment: Think of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$

Comment: The way you defined $M$ and $A,$ $\overline{M} = M\cup A $.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} \in M$ but I can't think of a sequence from $\{0,1\}$ that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. In fact, if $A=\{0,1\}$ then $\overline A=A$. This is because the only sequences from $\{0,1\}$ that converge are sequences that are eventually constant. As J. W. Tanner notes, $0$ and $1$ are limit points of $(0,1)$ that are not in $(0,1)$ (hence why $(0,1)$ is not a closed set).

Comment: In order for $A$ to be dense in $M$, $A$ must be a *subset* of $M$. In your example, $A$ is *disjoint* from $M.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  @J.W. Tanner: If I make the following change in my question, is the example OK now? Let M contain all real numbers in [0, 1] and let A contain all rational numbers in (0, 1).  Then $\overline{A} = M$.

But if I say M contains all real numbers in (0, 1), then $\overline{A} \neq M$.  Correct?

Comment: @NeedsProof:  that is correct; the closure of a set is always closed, and (0,1) is not (in the usual topology)

Answer (score 2):

$0.5$ can't be a limit point of a sequence consisting of $0$ and $1$; hence the statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

Does A consist just of 0 and 1? Then surely, A cannot be dense, as we can find a point in M which is not in A, nor a limit point of A, say 1/2. Maybe consider rationals in (0,1) as an example of a dense set in M.